# How do I suppress graph values from appearing in the legend on mouseover in AmCharts?

Tags: amcharts

I am using AmCharts with a legend and chart cursor enabled however I don't want the graph values to appear in the legend on mouseover. How do I disable that? Please see my screenshot.

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObUmk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the regular serial chart (post your code next time), you can suppress the legend value on mouseover by setting the legend's [`valueText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueText) to an empty string, e.g.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  legend: {
    valueText: "",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
});
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "valueText": ""
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
    "year": 1930,
    "italy": 1,
    "germany": 5,
    "uk": 3
  }, {
    "year": 1934,
    "italy": 1,
    "germany": 2,
    "uk": 6
  }, {
    "year": 1938,
    "italy": 2,
    "germany": 3,
    "uk": 1
  }, {
    "year": 1950,
    "italy": 3,
    "germany": 4,
    "uk": 1
  }, {
    "year": 1954,
    "italy": 5,
    "germany": 1,
    "uk": 2
  }, {
    "year": 1958,
    "italy": 3,
    "germany": 2,
    "uk": 1
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "integersOnly": true,
    "maximum": 6,
    "minimum": 1
  }],
  "startDuration": 0,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "place taken by Italy in [[category]]: [[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "title": "Italy",
    "valueField": "italy",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "balloonText": "place taken by Germany in [[category]]: [[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "title": "Germany",
    "valueField": "germany",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "balloonText": "place taken by UK in [[category]]: [[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "title": "United Kingdom",
    "valueField": "uk",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "year"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
```